# Lubuntu fails to install in VirtualBox

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, lubuntu

I am using the latest VirtualBox version (5.0.14) in my Windows 10 machine. I am trying to install Lubuntu 15.10 64-bit in VirtualBox.

"Try Lubuntu without installing" feature works fine. However, when I try "Install Lubuntu", after finishing the installation and rebooting I get the following error message. [image]

I reinstalled several times, getting the same result. What am I doing wrong here? Am I missing any important step in the installation process?

Comment: The fact that is doesn't boot might not have anything do with this message. AFAIK this is a common harmless message that you'll see on a VM.

Comment: @TomYan the machine never boots up. It just stays in that screen

Comment: There used to be a "Check CD for Defects" option you can try to make sure your install is good; could you try that?

Comment: Disable 'efi' mode and check virtualization options are enabled on your pc's bios

Comment: disable efi mode (on virtualbox)